# Embed a List inside a View to use Swipe Actions to delete Items?

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I have the problem that I want to have following layout of Views:

- TextField
- Items in the shopping list
- Adding Button

To use swipe actions of the SwiftUI list I would have to use it there, but as I saw this integration between is not possible, right?

It is possible to use UIKit elements to get a list in between, so that I can use the apple swipe actions?

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @State var shoppingList: [String] = []
    @State var listName = ""
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            TextField("Name", text: $listName)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.orange)
            ForEach(shoppingList, id:\.self){item in   <----- //Adding a List here 
                                                              //to use Swipe Action to delete an item?
                Text(item)
                    .padding(5)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            Button("Add Item"){
                shoppingList.append("Test \(shoppingList.count)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On delete only works on a list.

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @State var shoppingList: [String] = []
    @State var listName = ""
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            TextField("Name", text: $listName)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.orange)
            List {                                                    // ADDED
                ForEach(shoppingList, id:\.self){ item in
                    Text(item)
                        .padding(5)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9)
                        .background(Color.green)
                }.onDelete(perform: removeRow)                       // ADDED
            }                                                        // ADDED
            Button("Add Item"){
                shoppingList.append("Test \(shoppingList.count)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeRow(at offsets: IndexSet) {                          // ADDED
        shoppingList.remove(atOffsets: offsets)                     // ADDED
    }                                                               // ADDED
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that the list tries to get as much space as possible. I could use a section for the Adding button in the list itself but im not as free with the layout as I would be with having a button in a VStack.